# Deferred Lighting - How to map to the generated texture?

Tags: directx, hlsl, deferred-rendering, deferred-shading

I'm trying to implement deferred lighting and I have done the first and second pass but I'm stuck on the third as I don't know how to map from the current pixel being drawn to the generated texture with the light.

Generated texture with light calculated
[image]

Current picture
[image]

I would appreciate it if someone could help me figure out how to map my generated texture with the current pixel I'm drawing.

I don't know if it matters, but I'm working with DirectX but an explantion with OpenGL would also be welcomed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to load the lighting value at the position of the pixel.

```
// Example pixel shader DX11
float4 PixelShader(PixelLocation : SV_Position) : SV_Target0
{
     //...

     int3 SampleIndex = int3(PixelLocation.xy, 0);
     float4 lighting = LightingBuffer.Load(SampleIndex);

     //...
}
```

Info on [Load here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/bb509694(v=vs.85).aspx).